# enteries in column are automatically changed to upper case letters

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I am very new with Open Office and spread sheets in general. In a column whenever I add a new entry it changes all the letters to upper case. Is there a way to disable this? If not, many entries already have been made with lower case letters and it looks bad that the entries are the same except for their capitalization, so is there a way all the rest could be made all uppercase? For example in this one column when I try to add `A12b` it changes to `A12B` but it didn't use to and it looks bad now that there's a mix.

EDIT: It only happens on the **exact entry** T61p. For example if I type in T62p the p remains lower case.

Comment: I'm not sure if openoffice has the formula `=UPPER()`. You could add a column and use this on every cell, then copy/paste values to remove the formulas. This is for the second possibility.

Comment: OpenOffice uses auto-completion. So if there is a "T61P" in the table, "T61p" will be suggested to "T61P". Just disable in the options.